# How can I disable Firebase/Analytics logging in console of Xcode?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I use firebase analytics in my project, but it logging too much, such as "[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023080] Setting user property. Name, value: lifetime_user_engagement (_lte), 235099407...".

Answer (score 32):

To enable Analytics Debug mode on your development device, specify the following command line argument in Xcode :

```
-FIRDebugEnabled
```

This behavior persists until you explicitly disable Debug mode by specifying the following command line argument :

```
-FIRDebugDisabled
```

To enter the Arguments in Xcode Press, Follow the steps

In Xcode 8.x just select the project from the title bar and select Edit Schema, then select the Run debug and select the Arguments Tab from the popup window.

Comment: I found this piece of information on docs, but what the documentation didn't make clear to me is: I need to change it back before release or this flag only affect the debug scheme?

Comment: "Edit Schema" no longer exists, or is relocated deeper in Xcode 11 such that this no longer makes sense anymore.

Comment: @JohnPitts it still exists in Xcode 13 and works...

Answer (score 12):

In AppDelegate where your configure FirebaseApp, also add:

```
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually do anything.